# want fetch existing data from db in django. 1054 "Unknown column 'traders.id' in 'field list'" error getting. Id is automatically generate in db

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
def Fetch_data(request):
    #'q' is name given in form
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        data = Traders.objects.filter(traders_name__icontains=q)
    else:
        data = Traders.objects.all()
        
    return render(request,"fetch_data.html", {'data':data})
```

html file **template**

```
       <tbody>
            {% for data in data %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>{{data.traders_name}}</td>   
                <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td>{{data.registration_no}}</td>
                <td>{{data.address}}</td>
            </tr> -->
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTbaW.png)

Comment: i upload excel in mysql using python.. then i use python manage.py inspectdb > model.py command to create model in django. i want to fetch data from db in views.py..but it showing error as 1054 unknown column 'trader.id' in filed list. id column automatically generated in db...there is only 4 column in my excel  traders_name, email, registration_no, address...error pic uploaded above

Comment: can you post the text from the image in a quote or code block to allow it to be easily copy-pasted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.